# An internal error occurred during: "Uploading function code to Lambda" javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to upload a Lambda to AWS I get the following error

An internal error occurred during:

"Uploading function code to Lambda" javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Later versions of Eclipse use the Java 11 runtime, which removed this class among many others. However, I am sure now that Java 17 has been released, that this has been fixed in later versions of AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are encountering a tool issue while trying to directly upload code from Eclipse to AWS. This is not unnecessary.

You can instead use the Java runtime Lambda API within a Maven project, that works fine. That is, build the Lambda function using Maven, package the project into a JAR file, and then upload the Lambda function using the AWS Management Console.

Here is an example that builds a Lambda function that invokes several AWS services and will show you how to successfully build and deploy the AWS Lambda function (without using a tool).

This Lambda function detects PPE information (using Amazon Rekognition) in images located in an Amazon S3 bucket. See this example that is located in the **Amazon Rekognition DEV Guide**.

[Detect PPE in images with Amazon Rekognition using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/example_cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzerPPE_section.html)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I did what you said and it worked. Built my lambda locally. Created a lambda function on the console and then loaded  the jar file using the console. I would vote your reply up but I need 15 reputations to vote it up.

Comment: I find this a much better approach as opposed to fighting with a tool that works sometimes and does not other times. I am glad you got it working.